# React hook form input currentTarget input clear errors if not empty for current only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

Working on a contact form and and all of my fields are required. Now I have this onChangeInput function and I want to clear the error of that specific `currentTarget.name` on change. But not able to specify the the unique field name to clear the errors only for this field. Instead it removes all of them.

Ugly way which does work is by doing the following:

```
clearErrors("name");
clearErrors("message");
```

etc

is there a trick on how to remove only the specific input errors if it's not empty?

My code:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form"
import { FiUser, FiMail, FiPhone } from "react-icons/fi"

import Button from "./Button"

import { cn } from "@lib/utils"
import { ContactProps } from "types"

const Contact = () => {
  const requiredMessage = "Dit veld is verplicht"
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState<ContactProps>({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    message: ""
  })
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false)
  const [showSuccess, setShowSuccess] = useState(false)

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitSuccessful }
  } = useForm<ContactProps>({
    reValidateMode: "onSubmit"
  })

  const handleInputChange = (
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    setNewMessage({
      ...newMessage,
      [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
    })

    if (e.currentTarget.value === "") {
      clearErrors()
    }
  }

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ContactProps> = useCallback((data) => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      resolve()

      setIsSubmitted(true)

      setNewMessage({
        ...newMessage,
        ...data
      })

      console.log(newMessage)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (errors.email || errors.message || errors.name || errors.phone) {
      setShowSuccess(false)
    }

    if (isSubmitSuccessful) {
      setShowSuccess(true)

      reset({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        message: ""
      })

      setNewMessage({ name: "", email: "", phone: "", message: "" })
    }
  }, [formState, reset])

  const name = register("name", {
    required: "Voor-en Achternaam is verplicht"
  })

  const email = register("email", {
    required: "E-mailadres is verplicht",
    pattern: {
      value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
      message: "Voer een geldig e-mailadres in"
    }
  })

  const phone = register("phone", {
    required: "Telefoonnummer is verplicht",
    pattern: {
      value: /^[0-9]+$/,
      message: "Please enter numbers only"
    }
  })

  const message = register("message", {
    required: "Bericht is verplicht"
  })

  return (
    <div className="pt-16 pb-12 bg-primary sm:rounded-2xl text-midnight">
      <h2 className="text-3xl leading-none text-center sm:text-5xl lg:text-6xl font-playfair">
        Stel hier al je vragen!
      </h2>

      <p className="max-w-lg pt-4 pb-8 mx-auto text-center text-md">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, odio illum
        reprehenderit necessitatibus esse ex eos dolor sapiente.
      </p>

      <form
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="max-w-5xl mx-auto sm:px-8"
      >
        <div className="gap-8 space-y-4 lg:gap-10 md:flex md:space-y-0">
          <div className="w-full space-y-4">
            <label className="block space-y-3">
              <span className="text-xl font-playfair">Naam en achternaam*</span>
              <div className="relative flex items-center group">
                <FiUser className="absolute w-6 h-6 pointer-events-none left-5" />
                <input
                  {...name}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  value={newMessage.name}
                  className={cn(
                    errors.name
                      ? "border-red-600 placeholder:text-red-600"
                      : "border-midnight placeholder:text-midnight",
                    "w-full py-3 pr-5 bg-white border-2 outline-none pl-14 rounded-xl"
                  )}
                  placeholder={
                    errors.name ? requiredMessage : "Naam en achternaam"
                  }
                />
              </div>
            </label>

            <label className="block space-y-3">
              <span className="text-xl font-playfair">E-mailadres*</span>
              <div className="relative flex items-center group text-midnight">
                <FiMail className="absolute w-6 h-6 pointer-events-none left-5" />
                <input
                  {...email}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  value={newMessage.email}
                  className={cn(
                    errors.email
                      ? "border-red-600 placeholder:text-red-600"
                      : "border-midnight placeholder:text-midnight",
                    "w-full py-3 pr-5 bg-white border-2 outline-none pl-14 rounded-xl"
                  )}
                  placeholder={errors.email ? requiredMessage : "E-mailadres"}
                />
              </div>
            </label>

            <label className="block space-y-3">
              <span className="text-xl font-playfair">Telefoonnummer*</span>
              <div className="relative flex items-center group text-midnight">
                <FiPhone className="absolute w-6 h-6 pointer-events-none left-5"></FiPhone>
                <input
                  {...phone}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  value={newMessage.phone}
                  className={cn(
                    errors.phone
                      ? "border-red-600 placeholder:text-red-600"
                      : "border-midnight placeholder:text-midnight",
                    "w-full py-3 pr-5 bg-white border-2 outline-none pl-14 rounded-xl"
                  )}
                  placeholder={
                    errors.phone ? requiredMessage : "Telefoonnummer"
                  }
                />
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className="w-full space-y-3">
            <label className="block space-y-3">
              <span className="text-xl font-playfair">Je bericht*</span>
              <textarea
                {...message}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={newMessage.message}
                rows={10}
                className={cn(
                  errors.message
                    ? "border-red-600 placeholder:text-red-600"
                    : "border-midnight placeholder:text-midnight",
                  "w-full px-5 py-3 bg-white border-2 outline-none resize-none rounded-xl"
                )}
                placeholder={errors.message ? requiredMessage : "Bericht..."}
              />
            </label>

            <div className="flex justify-end">
              <Button
                buttonType="submit"
                text="Versturen"
                buttonClass="btn-secondary"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {showSuccess && isSubmitted && (
          <div className="mt-5 font-semibold border-2 bg-success alert border-success">
            <div>
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 stroke-current"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                />
              </svg>
              <span>
                Bedankt {newMessage.name} voor het versturen van je bericht!
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contact
```